# Number base conversion

Tags: java

I'd like to convert integers from decimal base to quaternal base. What is the more concise way to do it ?

```
// From 4-base to decimal
int d = Integer.parseInt("10", 4); // 5

// From decimal to decimal string 
String b10 = String.valueOf(d);    // "5"

// From decimal to 4-base string ?
String b4 = yourMagicFunction(d, 4);  // "10"
```

Comment: To convert an integer from one base to another base, you can use `Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(number, base1), base2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just looking for `Integer.toString(int, int)`?

```
String b4 = Integer.toString(5, 4); // b4 = "11"
```

(Note the 11 rather than 10... parsing "10" base 4 gives 4, not 5.)

It's not clear what you're looking for beyond `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` and `Integer.toString(int, int)`...

Comment: +1 : Thanks. Yes, it was simple but had a long time without Java :p

Comment: Oh my god, but you are Jon Skeet !

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.toString(d, 4);
```

The [`Integer.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) method can convert to any radix between [`Character.MIN_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_RADIX) and  [`Character.MAX_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX).

However, Java `int`s (such as `d`) are stored as binary internally, not decimal.

Comment: What do you mean by "the source is binary"?

Comment: @JonSkeet, just that `d` is a two's complement binary integer.

Comment: It's still not really clear what you mean to me. An integer is an integer. It's only "decimal" or "binary" *after formatting*.

Comment: @Jon, JLS 4.2 requires that it's a "signed two's-complement integer" in memory, which also implies it's binary.  The OP talks about converting from "decimal to decimal string", implying that the internal representation is decimal.  I just wanted to indicate that the actual internal representation is binary.

Comment: The internal representation isn't particularly relevant, IMO - it's just an integer. I thought the question made it fairly clear he was talking about *string* representations.

Comment: @Jon, take a look at the second code line (starting `String b10`) in his question.  He was converting from an `int` (`d`) to a decimal string (`b10`).  He said that was converting "From decimal to decimal string".  `d` is neither a string representation nor a decimal.  I thought it was worth clearing up that `d` is not a decimal.  I agree that wasn't the main point of the question, but it is a related topic.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I admit I should have said *binary* or *internal representation*, don't fight with Sir Skeet about this :D